# Some of the Windows11 startup folder items don't run with windows

Tags: windows-11, autohotkey

I am using Win11 22H2 Build 22621.1485

Some items/programs, when put into the common or admin's startup folder (in: C:\Users\iPC\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup ) are run correctly when the admin/user logs in.
But some, like Utorrent, and ahk scripts pose problems (read 'don't run').

I've tried many solutions over many days. But have not come to know yet if the problem lies with Ahk script files, or with windows. I've also tried inserting those programs shortcuts to windows registry to make them run. Have also tried to create windows scheduled tasks for them.  But even though some simpler programs, like notepad, do run. but those which were posing problems, didn't run with these alternatives also.

I'm the sole admin on this local work group pc. No network, no special environment, nothing.

I've also tried these non-working apps shortcuts in the common startup folder here: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup . But no success.

---

I'm pretty sure that such problems only started after updating windows11 to current build and after updating ahk to v2 (although now problem doesn't go away, even if I uninstalled ahk v2.0).

---

As a workaround, I've created a startup.bat file and gave the paths of all programs which I want to run on every boot (even some of them were being run successfully thru normal start menu's startup folder entry).

Could anyone guide or tell if this could be windows or ahk or utorrent problem?

Comment: [Edit] your question to specify where exactly you are putting these applications you want automatically start.

Comment: `Utorrent` will be blocked by defender out of the box.  You should probably pick a better torrent client.  You will find `qBittorrent` will also be blocked without an amendment to your allowed list but it isn't as evil as `uTorrent`.

Comment: @ramhound but I've already stated in the very beginning that 'when some items/programs put into start menu's startup folder....'. 
Isn't it clear enough?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas , but I've defender disabled on my windows (I'm using Avast). And 
Moreover, when create a scheduled task to run uTorrent, then it does run successfully. As told in the question, I'm the sole and full admin on this standalone pc.
Although I've been using uTorrent for years, I'd try your suggested program qBitTorrent also, and see the result.

Comment: @BathindaHelper - I am looking for you to specify the full path. I have my reasons. If you don’t want to clarify your question I won’t be able to help you.

Comment: @ramhound OH!! I couldn't understand fully (that you're asking for full path). I've tried putting these in my own (admin user's) startup folder (C:\Users\iPC\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup) and also under common startup folder (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup). Same results. Regarding at least one item (utorrent), I've found that it does run in taskmanager, but doesn't show anywhere on taskbar or in taskbar tray.

Comment: @Ramhound I've replied in the comment above. Perhaps you've missed my reply.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I've installed qBittorrent. But it too doesn't show either in the taskbar tray or even in taskmanager. I've created a short YT video to show this problem. See the video here: https://youtu.be/VfFzxghwQhQ

Comment: @BathindaHelper - You are right. Include that vital information in the body of the question. I purposely skipped reading your comment. It’s something I suggested on April 3rd.

Comment: @Ramhound done! Edited the question, included both full paths where I tried putting those apps' shortcuts.

Comment: Avast is bad. Mainly because they are basically giving away spyware for free. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avast#Collection_and_sale_of_user_data